# UISwitch: Swift 3: Programmatically

Tags: uikit, swift3, uiswitch

How can I programmatically add a uiswitch and call an action when on and one when off? Ive been searching for hours now. Can I please have some help? I know how to add the switch but it stays on the screen no matter what scene I'm on. So far, I've been able to add the button and make it switch from on to off, but for some reason the switch just says on the screen in every scene. I was lost after that so I followed this; from [How to programmatically put a UISwitch in a SpriteKit/Skcene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835826/how-to-programmatically-put-a-uiswitch-in-a-spritekit-skcene)

Yes it is possible. Just use this code in your SKScene class:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let switchDemo = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(150, 300, 0, 0))
    switchDemo.on = true
    switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view!.addSubview(switchDemo)
}
```

Helper method:

```
func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!)
{
    if (sender.on == true){
        print("on")
    }
    else{
        print("off")
    }
}
```

I kept getting errors so I did what Xcode suggested which ended up with the SIGBART error.

Comment: Update your question with what you have so far. And clearly explain what issues you are having with it.

Comment: Sorry, Im kinda new to stack overflow. I did what you said to in an edit.

Comment: You are calling the selector wrong in the action part of switchDemo.addTarget(...). Check my answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are calling the selector wrong on the addTarget action line. They finally changed it at one point in Swift 2 to get rid of using strings for selector method calls, which now makes them a lot less error prone.

Change it to this (Swift 3 syntax)

```
switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

You basically call #selector in the action parameter and include the method you want to call, in your case switchValueDidChange. Note the (_:) syntax at the end, thats indicating that the method you want to call takes a parameter, in your case a UISwitch.

```
 func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     ...
 }
```

If you want to call a regular method that takes no parameters e.g

```
 func switchValueDidChange() {
 }
```

than you would just say

```
switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
```

without the (_:) syntax.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ive done everything you have said to do but I'm getting "Cannot convert value of type 'UISwitch!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UISwitch>.Type') to expected argument type 'UISwitch!'" and "Cannot convert value of type 'UISwitch!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UISwitch>.Type') to expected argument type 'UISwitch!'"

Comment: You probably made a mistake in the parameter of switchValueDidChange. Check out this article http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/uiswitch-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift

Comment: In Swift 3, my addTarget() call had to be a bit different: `switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(switch:)), for: .valueChanged)`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, I just updated my answer for Swift 3.

Comment: Just a minor correction, you need to use underscore in function declaration if you want to use this format : #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:). Otherwise, replace it with parameter name like : #selector(switchValueDidChange(sender:)

Answer (score 10):

**Updated to swift 5**

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let switchDemo = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 0, height: 0))
    switchDemo.isOn = true
    switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.view!.addSubview(switchDemo)
}
```

Helper method:

```
@objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch!) {
    if (sender.isOn){
        print("on")
    }
    else{
        print("off")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**With parameter:**

```
@IBOutlet var categorySwitch:UISwitch!

var categorySwitchIsOn:Bool =  false
```

***On viewDidLoad:***

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        categorySwitch.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.categorySwitchValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
```

***Associated function:***

```
func categorySwitchValueChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){

    if sender.isOn {
        categorySwitchIsOn =  true

    } else {

        categorySwitchIsOn =  false
    }


}
```