# Add UISwitch to subtitle style of tableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I want to use subtitle style of table view cell (not the custom one), and also I need to have an `UISwitch` in the right side of the cell. 
if the name of the cell is `TitleCell`
I know I can add a UISwitch programmatically to it by using this line of code:

```
TitleCell.accessoryView = UISwitch()
```

But can I have access to this `UISwitch` and using it as an outlet and giving it an action?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can give an action to the switch programmatically by calling addTarget (see [UISwitch: Swift 3: Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759253/uiswitch-swift-3-programmatically) ).

Also consider moving to a custom cell xib/class. It is not hard to set up, but then you have full control over what is there and how it is laid out.

Comment: thanks for your help. I usually use custom style, but as Im working on the setting page and all cells must have icon, subtitle style with an image is quite prefect for my work and I don't need worry about the size of the image and constraints. I looked at the website that you post it, but they use normal add to subview, but the adding with method that I use, doesn't give me any thing to access to the UIswitch inside it, at least I don't know how

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't work if you addTarget when you have an accessoryView ?

Comment: Also note that if you do addTarget , you get your UISwitch as the "sender" parameter to your selector. You can assign a tag inside UISwitch (`mySwitch.tag = rowIndex`), and be able to find the cell by index with that from the action callback.

Answer (score 0):

After assigning the switch to the accessory view you can access it with

```
if let mySwitch = TitleCell.accessoryView as? UISwitch {
   // it's the switch, you can use it.
}
```

However you are encouraged to design a **custom** cell with an outlet by subclassing `UITableViewCell`

And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.